# "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" while super

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I administrate Redmine (2.3.2.stable.231, rails 3.2.13) with some custom scripts and it used to work quite well. However recently, when my script tries to destroy an issue by Redmine API, it gets (only sometimes, not everytime) HTTP 500 because of:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
 app/models/issue.rb:159:in `create_or_update'
 app/models/issue.rb:1347:in `recalculate_attributes_for'
 app/models/issue.rb:1311:in `update_parent_attributes'
 app/models/issue.rb:173:in `destroy'
 app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:313:in `block in destroy'
 app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:311:in `each'
 app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:311:in `destroy'
```

Which is quite surprising because issue.rb (Issue class of course inherits from ActiveRecord::Base) is

```
158   def create_or_update
159     super
160   ensure
161     @status_was = nil
162   end
163   private :create_or_update
```

I can't see any [] operator usage in line 159, neither another function call on traceback, so how is this even possible? Am I missing anything about ruby's super? How do I trace it further?

Comment: `super` will call the `create_or_update` method on the parent class of `Issue` (? — I guess it’s an `Issue` class.)

Comment: Will it? There's nothing about it on traceback. Anyway I checked it, and ActiveRecord::Base seems not to use [] operator either [link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create_or_update)

Comment: Racing condition? I would guess that the instance itself is gone when it reaches the **super** line. Is this a multithread thing going on?

Comment: Well, Redmine itself is multithreading, but I'm pretty sure the traceback runs in a single thread. What's more, the instance of Issue is still present in database after fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer by accident - the reason of `NoMethodError` was plugin called redmine_backlogs. It creates `rb_issue_history` table, with some serialized historic data for issues (if needed) and of course `history` column has limited capacity. We needed to keep some important long-term issues, and for them `history` field became pushed to its limit. That caused errors during loading object from DB.

However I still suspect that something is missing on traceback. The error itself occurs in `init_history` method in `rb_issue_history.rb` model - as I said, I found this out by accident, in other log files.